# eval function to set values of dynamically generated fields

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set values of  dynamically generated fields using eval() function in javascript.Since I don't know the name of the field beforehand.

Here is what I have done.

here last two parameters are the name of the fields whose values I want to set.
and the first two values are the values which I want to set them to.

```
function onRefreshTypes(fuelType,startType,fuelTypes,startTypes)
{

    var fuelTypes1=fuelTypes;
    var startTypes1=startTypes;


    eval("document.frm."+fuelTypes1+".value="+fuelType);//here is where I am getting error
    eval("document.frm."+startTypes1+".value="+startType);//here is where I am getting error
}
```

here frm is the name of the form in which the fields are generated
I am getting an error "Unexpected identifier"
where am I going wrong?

Comment: You should [avoid using eval()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil) where possible. You can use dynamic fields using the square bracket notation. `document.frm[fuelTypes1].value=`

Comment: @MikeCauser isn't it exactly what I've suggested in my answer?

Comment: @Pavlo heh, it would appear so. I should really scroll down first :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `eval()` here, use square brackets notation:

```
document.frm[fuelTypes1].value = fuelType;
```